# Python: take unique dates in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
                       price
Date
2022-01-01 19:20:00    100   
2022-01-01 19:27:00    100
2022-01-02 19:31:00    102
```

I want the dataframe to only have unique dates:

```
                       price
Date
2022-01-01 19:20:00    100   
2022-01-02 19:31:00    102
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `duplicated`:

```
# pre-requisite
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df[~df['Date'].dt.date.duplicated()]
```

Or if working with the index:

```
df[~df.index.to_series().dt.date.duplicated().values]
```

Output:

```
                 Date  price
0 2022-01-01 19:20:00    100
2 2022-01-02 19:31:00    102
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the date from the datetime column using `df.Date.dt.date`, put that into a new column using `assign`, and after that use `drop_duplicates` based on only that column. Last, you might want to drop the newly create column that has only the date information. In code that reads

```py
df = (
    df.assign(new_date=lambda df:df.Date.dt.date)
   .drop_duplicates(subset=["new_date"])
   .drop(columns=["new_date"])
)
```